# wpf open PDF file in Adobe Reader with a click on a button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ado.net

I need a button to open a *PDF* file with Adobe Reader. I have the following code but it does not work. The file is inside Books folder on my application.

```
private void openPDF(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        bookPDF = "/Books/" + dataRow.ItemArray[6].ToString();
        Uri pdf = new Uri(bookPDF, UriKind.Relative);
        process.StartInfo.FileName = new Uri(bookPDF, UriKind.Relative).ToString();
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Could not open the file.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
    }
}
```

I tested a simple string with a test pdf file to open and it opens.

```
...
String file = "C:\\pdf\\Windows_Server_2008_R2_Unleashed.pdf";
process.StartInfo.FileName = file;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: If you double-click in Explorer, does that file open in in Reader? Also I notice you are using forward slashes instead of back slashes for "Books".

Comment: what do you have in `dataRow`

Comment: dataRow.ItemArray[6].ToString() has the file name like "123.pdf"

Comment: Could it be, that you just forgot to set "Copy to Output Directory" on the Pdf files? If you use the path "Books\123.pdf" the Books-folder should be in the same directory as the builded exe.

Comment: Claudio P, that was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change your 6th line:

```
bookPDF = "/Books/" + dataRow.ItemArray[6].ToString();
```

to:

```
bookPDF = "Books\\" + dataRow.ItemArray[6].ToString();
```

Microsoft Windows naming convention uses backslashes as separator within paths
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can change your 6th line to :

```
bookPDF = string.Format(@"books\{0}", dataRow.ItemArray[6].ToString());
```

And this should work if you have books folder in your application directory which has specified pdf.

Comment: I have a "Books" inside the application directory, but it is still not working. Just to be clear, I can open the file in explorer.